# DHT InfoHash Lookup sequence. PeerID vs InfoHash

Tags: bittorrent, dht, kademlia

I know there is a previous question about this somewhere on SO, but I cannot find it again. The relationship between NodeId and InfoHash.
Is the following diagram roughly correct?

[image]

**Background** *(no need to read)*

I'm trying to implement my own DHT/bittorrent application in Java.
I know that there are already some excellent implementations that I will never better. But this is purely a hedonistic pursuit.
What was it Kennedy said? "we choose to do this not because it is easy.."

I have conquered the easy part, which is to write the low level socket handling and Remote Procedure Call syntax etc.
Now I am on to the hard part, I must behave responsibly and service incoming requests on the DHT. (maintain KBuckets etc.)

Comment: perhaps one of these? https://stackoverflow.com/q/29958613/1362755 https://stackoverflow.com/q/44104242/1362755

Comment: The first one is the one I found. I hadn't seen the second one, which was helpful. So essentially I'm responsible for the area around my nodeid. (Won't bep42 skew the dht to hashes of popular IP octets?). But when I perform searches I can treat the information as disposable? Am I right that a 'values' response is a hit, and nodes a 'try again'? I read somewhere of one client that returns values and nodes. How do you deal with that?

Comment: You should update your question if you wish to revise it after reading the linked ones.

Comment: @the8472 I will update this when I finally 'get it'. I have another question open 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52779558/dht-routing-table-why-use-buckets-and-not-a-map
About the purpose of buckets, which is the area I'm still struggling with.

Comment: @Richard did you look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that diagram is correct. Here some python code that implements `FIND_VALUE` algorithm you describe:

```
async def _get(self, key):
    """Fetch the value associated with KEY from the network"""
    uid = pack(key)
    queried = set()
    while True:
        # retrieve the k nearest peers and remove already queried peers
        peers = await self.peers((None, None), uid)
        peers = [address for address in peers if address not in queried]
        # no more peer to query, the key is not found in the dht
        if not peers:
            raise KeyError(unpack(uid))
        # query selected peers
        queries = dict()
        for address in peers:
            query = self._protocol.rpc(address, "value", uid)
            queries[address] = query
        responses = await gather(queries, return_exceptions=True)
        for (address, response) in responses.items():
            queried.add(address)
            if isinstance(response, Exception):
                continue
            elif response[0] == b"VALUE":
                value = response[1]
                if hash(value) == unpack(uid):
                    # store it
                    @h.transactional
                    def add(tr, key, value):
                        tr.add("QADOM:MAPPING", key, "value", value)

                    await self._run(add, self._hoply, key, value)
                    # at last!
                    return value
                else:
                    log.warning(
                        "[%r] bad value returned from %r", self._uid, address
                    )
                    await self.blacklist(address)
                    continue
            elif response[0] == b"PEERS":
                await self._welcome_peers(response[1])
            else:
                await self.blacklist(address)
                log.warning(
                    "[%r] unknown response %r from %r",
                    self._uid,
                    response[0],
                    address,
```

This is extract from [qadom project peer.py](https://github.com/amirouche/qadom/blob/master/qadom/peer.py).